# Writing from Powershell to Excel: How to set the cell format for the value?

Tags: excel, powershell

I am reading values from different Excel files, and composing a new one containing information from all the others. While doing that, Excel seems to automatically change '.' to a comma ','. How do I prevent that?

I am using Powershell ISE on Win10 and Office365. I tried reading and writing 'value2' and 'text' and writing those. I tried casting the value2 to string when I write it. This did not work. The variables in Powershell hold the correct values as strings. The moment I save the new Excel file, the correct format is gone.

Example: Value is "123.456". I can read it, the Powershell variable shows "123.456". I write it to Excel and open the Excel afterwards, it reads:
123,456 and interprets it as number instead of a text.

## How I read the value

```
[...]
$tmp += ($worksheet.cells.item($intRow,$col).value2)
```

## How I write the value (I tried "value", and "text" for both)

```
[...]
elseif($value -eq 6){
 $sheet.Cells.item($intRow,$columncounter).value2 = ($tmp[$value]).ToString()
}
[...]
```

## This is how I open the excel file for writing:

```
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible=$false
$resultbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
$sheet = $resultbook.ActiveSheet
$sheet.Name = "Data"
```

## This is how I save the excel file

```
$resultbook.SaveAs($name)
$resultbook.close()
```

Expected: Input == Output, example: 1234.5678 --> 1234.5678

Actual Result: Input != Output, example 1234.5678 --> 1234,5678

It works fine for all other strings, texts, numbers except those containing dots.

I presume there must be a way to specify the cell format in the target file, however I did not find any documentation on that.

Comment: Try to cast with [decimal]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I tried it but it did not work. Maybe the reason is some kind of country setting since here in germany we actually use the comma as decimal separator.

Comment: Working in PowerShell with Excel you *always* need english syntax, for formulas as well! E. G. mycell.Formula = "SVERWEIS(…) => Error, mycell.Formula = "VLOOKUP(…) => OK. The same for comma and decimal point.

Comment: I agree, the problem is getting excel to acknowledge that the numbers i write shall be treated as text and not as numbers. I just tried adding a single quote in front of the value and that seems to work, however there should be a way to do that differently as well.

Comment: You can also try to format the cell as a text before, e. g. $worksheet.cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "@"